# Javascript error when sharing with LinkedIn Share API

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
 $(".btn_li").click(function() {
    window.open("http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url='+document.URL+'&amp;title=Webpage Title;summary=Webpage Summary", "LinkedIn", "width=660,height=400,scrollbars=no;resizable=no");
try { 
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social', 'LinkedIn', "Page URL"]); 
 } catch(err){}        
return false;
});
```

and call this from:

```
<div class="btn_li"></div>
```

When this button is clicked, the LinkedIn error I receive is, "There was an unexpected problem that prevented us from completing your request." This tells me that the parameters are not being passed correctly.

Any advice?

NB: This is a new problem from my original question: [Add Google Analytics Click (event) tracking code to Javascript window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533546/add-google-analytics-click-event-tracking-code-to-javascript-window-open).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode each parameter, see the [LinkedIn docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-linkedin).

```
 $(".btn_li").click(function() {

    var articleUrl = encodeURIComponent('http://medium.com');
     var articleTitle = encodeURIComponent('Meduim');
     var articleSummary = encodeURIComponent('Blog posts');
     var articleSource = encodeURIComponent('Medium');
     var goto = 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true'+
         '&url='+articleUrl+
         '&title='+articleTitle+
         '&summary='+articleSummary+
         '&source='+articleSource;
     window.open(goto, "LinkedIn", "width=660,height=400,scrollbars=no;resizable=no");        
return false;
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/JaJb4/)

Comment: Thanks for the response Justin, no change I'm afraid. I actually started off with quotes and thought I'd try something else.

Comment: var articleUrl = encodeURIComponent('http://medium.com'); it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to encode this correctly, for instance..

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}

$(".btn_li").click(function() {
    var url = fixedEncodeURIComponent('http://yourURL.com');
    window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=" + url);
});
```

The Microsoft Developer Network documentation says to never use encodeURIComponent() directly, but to use this function.  Take a look: **[MDN Web Documentation on encodeURIComponont()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)**.

I have also fixed your url, `/share-offsite/` is the new standard, `shareArticle?` is the old standard that has been deprecated.  Source: [**LinkedIn Documentation: Share On LinkedIn, Section: "Customized URL"**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context).

Finally, the `title`, `summary`, and `source` arguments have all also been deprecated.  You can only use `og:` tags in the `<head>` block of your HTML source to fill these fields in.  For instance, this will look like...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

Want to see if you got it right?  Test your own website at [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).